# R data.table breaks in exported functions

Tags: r, data.table, devtools

I'm having a problem getting data.table to work in roxygen2 exported functions.

Here's a simple, fake function in a file called foo.R (located in the R directory of my package) which uses data.table:

```
#' Data.table test function
#' @export
foo <- function() {
  m <- data.table(c1 = c(1,2,3))
  print(is.data.table(m))
  m[,sum(c1)]
}
```

If I copy and paste this function into R, this function works fine:

```
> foo <- function() {
+   m <- data.table(c1 = c(1,2,3))
+   print(is.data.table(m))
+   m[,sum(c1)]
+ }
> foo()
[1] TRUE
[1] 6
```

But if I simply load the exported function, R thinks that the data.table is a data.frame and breaks:

```
> rm(foo)
> load_all()
Loading test_package
> foo
function() {
  m <- data.table(c1 = c(1,2,3))
  print(is.data.table(m))
  m[,sum(c1)]
}
<environment: namespace:test_package>
> foo()
[1] TRUE
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : object 'c1' not found
```

What's up?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @GSee for the help. Looks like this is actually a devtools issue. Check out the interactive command line code below.

After loading the test_package library, `foo` runs correctly:

```
> foo
function ()
{
    m <- data.table(c1 = c(1, 2, 3))
    print(is.data.table(m))
    m[, sum(c1)]
}
<environment: namespace:test_package>
> foo()
[1] TRUE
[1] 6
```

Running `load_all()` breaks foo:

```
> load_all()
Loading test_package
> foo()
[1] TRUE
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : object 'c1' not found
```

Somehow `source('R/foo.R')` revives foo functionality:

```
> source('R/foo.R')
> foo
function() {
  m <- data.table(c1 = c(1,2,3))
  print(is.data.table(m))
  m[,sum(c1)]
}
> foo()
[1] TRUE
[1] 6
```

And future calls to `load_all()` don't break `foo` again:

```
> load_all()
Loading test_package
> foo
function() {
  m <- data.table(c1 = c(1,2,3))
  print(is.data.table(m))
  m[,sum(c1)]
}
> foo()
[1] TRUE
[1] 6
```

Also, I updated to devtools 1.5 and tried adding `.datatable.aware=TRUE`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Are you sure the `foo` in your package is exactly the same (i.e. you didn't leave out the comma between `x[` and `col3`?

Comment: They're the same. I literally copy-and-pasted the function from the file foo.R (shown above) into the R command line.

Comment: Check `yourpackagename::foo` on the command line to make sure that they really are the same.  Just because the file you see on your editor looks like X doesn't mean the function in the package that is loaded in your R session is the same.

Comment: Yep, they look the same. I edited the question to include this check.

Comment: Is data.table in Depends or Imports in your package?

Comment: I updated the sample code to more simply illustrate the problem.

Comment: note that in the first code block above you have `m[,sum(c2)]` and the rest are `m[,sum(c1)]`... probably copy/paste error; not saying it's related to the problem

Comment: Do you have this problem if you build and load the package, or only if you're using `load_all()`?

Comment: Great idea. I built the package, installed it, ran library(test_package), and now it works. ...but I don't understand why. :)

Comment: Try putting `.datatable.aware=TRUE` on a line in one of your R files and see if `load_all()` works.  I think this [LINK](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/192) might be related -- updating `devtools` may solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for finding that link! `.datatable.aware=TRUE` and updating `devtools` didn't help, but sourcing the file directly seemed to negate `load_all()` breaking `foo`.

Comment: It might be an interaction between devtools and data.table - data.table does some unusual stuff to change the behaviour of `[`.

Comment: @GSee, kjmij, hadley, just tested on `devtools` 1.5. Using `.datatable.aware=TRUE` works just fine! This brings back to the same issue GSee has linked.

Comment: @hadley, `get(".Depends", "package:<package_name>")` does not return `data.table` when loaded with `devtools:::load_all()` and this is one of the things `data.table:::cedta()` checks under the hood to see if a package is *data.table aware*. Why doesn't `devtools` return "data.table", even if the package depends on it?

Comment: When you install the package and do: `require(test); ls("package:test", all=TRUE)`, you get ".Depends" and "foo", whereas this `.Depends` is not when loaded with `load_all()` from `devtools`.

Comment: Ah, I had put .datatable.aware within the `foo` function. But this works when I place it outside of the function.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help all! This is my first SO post, so I'm not familiar with the common courtesies here. Do I "Answer Your Question" myself? Or do I leave that for @GSee since the .datatable.aware=TRUE suggestion was his/hers?

Comment: @Arun because we don't create that data structure (probably because we didn't know about it). We'd love a devtools pull request that added this functionality

Comment: Is this the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/q/24501245/513006? The only reason I wonder is that the `.data.table.aware` worked in that case, but not here. That question uses `devtools:create` to generate a reproducible example.

Comment: Can't replicate this issue anymore: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/192#issuecomment-105451177

Comment: @krlmlr I am using devtools_2.2.1 and I still had to add `.datatable.aware=TRUE` to get my package with data.table to work.  Adding `Depends: data.table` to the DESCRIPTION file was not enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue, as @GSee pointed out (under comments) seems to be [**this issue**](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/192) still.

In order to find out if a package is *data.table aware*, `data.table` calls the function `cedta()`, which is:

```
> data.table:::cedta
function (n = 2L) 
{
    te = topenv(parent.frame(n))
    if (!isNamespace(te)) 
        return(TRUE)
    nsname = getNamespaceName(te)
    ans = nsname == "data.table" || "data.table" %chin% names(getNamespaceImports(te)) || 
        "data.table" %chin% tryCatch(get(".Depends", paste("package", 
            nsname, sep = ":"), inherits = FALSE), error = function(e) NULL) || 
        (nsname == "utils" && exists("debugger.look", parent.frame(n + 
            1L))) || nsname %chin% cedta.override || identical(TRUE, 
        tryCatch(get(".datatable.aware", asNamespace(nsname), 
            inherits = FALSE), error = function(e) NULL))
    if (!ans && getOption("datatable.verbose")) 
        cat("cedta decided '", nsname, "' wasn't data.table aware\n", 
            sep = "")
    ans
}
<bytecode: 0x7ff67b9ca190>
<environment: namespace:data.table>
```

The relevant check here is:

```
"data.table" %chin% get(".Depends", paste("package", nsname, sep=":"), inherits=FALSE)
```

When a package *depends* on `data.table`, the above command should return `TRUE` - that is, if you installed the package via `R CMD INSTALL` and then loaded the package. This is because, when you load the package, R by default creates a ".Depends" variable in the namespace as well. If you did:

```
ls("package:test", all=TRUE)
# [1] ".Depends" "foo"
```

However, when you do `devtools:::load_all()`, this variable doesn't seem to be set.

```
# new session + set path to package's dir
devtools:::load_all()
ls("package:test", all=TRUE)
# [1] "foo"
```

So, `cedta()` doesn't get to know that this package indeed *depends* on `data.table`. However, when you manually set `.datatable.aware=TRUE`, the line:

```
identical(TRUE, get(".datatable.aware", asNamespace(nsname), inherits = FALSE))
```

gets executed, which will return TRUE and therefore overcomes the issue. But the fact that `devtools` doesn't place the `.Depends` variable in the package's namespace is still there.

All in all, this is really *not* an issue with `data.table`.