# r - data.table and testthat package

Tags: r, data.table, r-package, testthat

I am building a package which works with data.table and which should be tested using package testthat.
While the code works fine when calling from the command line, I run into issues when calling from a test case. It seems that the [] function from the base package, i.e. the function for data.frames is used when running the tests.

I have created a minimum example which can be found here: https://github.com/utalo/test_datatable_testthat

The package contains a single function:

```
test <- function() {
   dt <- data.table(MESSAGE="Test 1234567890",TYPE="ERROR")
   dt[,.(MESSAGE=strwrap(MESSAGE,width = 10)),by=.(TYPE)]
}
```

When calling `test.datatable.testthat:::test()` from the command line I get the expected result:

```
    TYPE    MESSAGE
 1: ERROR       Test
 2: ERROR 1234567890
```

However, when executing the following unit test:

```
test_that("Test package",{
  dt <- test()

  expected_res <- structure(list(TYPE = c("ERROR", "ERROR"),
                             MESSAGE = c("Test","1234567890")),
                        row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table","data.frame"),
                        .Names = c("TYPE", "MESSAGE"))

  expect_equal(dt,expected_res)
})
```

I get an error:

```
1
1. Error: Test package -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
could not find function "."
1: withCallingHandlers(eval(code, new_test_environment), error = capture_calls, message = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
2: eval(code, new_test_environment)
3: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
4: test() at test.R:4
5: dt[, .(MESSAGE = strwrap(MESSAGE, width = 10)), by = .(TYPE)] at test.datatable.testthat/R/hello.R:5
6: `[.data.table`(dt, , .(MESSAGE = strwrap(MESSAGE, width = 10)), by = .(TYPE)) at C:\Users\D057806\Documents\R\test.datatable.testthat/R/hello.R:5
7: `[.data.frame`(x, i, j)
```

As you can see, within the test the [] of data.frame is called.
My first guess was that the dependency to the data.table package is not declared correctly. This is my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: test.datatable.testthat
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1
Date: 2016-04-07
Authors@R: person("First", "Last", email = "first.last@example.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: What license is it under?
LazyData: TRUE
Depends:
    data.table
Suggests:
     testthat
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
```

According to [Using data.table package inside my own package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package) it should be sufficient to declare data.table as a dependent package. However, this does not seem to be the case here.

Any clues as to why my function is working when being called directly but not in the context of testthat?

Comment: Does the issue persist if you *import* data.table, and add `import(data.table)` to your namespace? I ask because [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23279604/559784) comes to mind.. and I'm guessing it's the same issue with `testthat`.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the pointer! This seems to be part of the issue. If I change the depends statement to import it works in the test example, however not in my original code. I will try to reproduce this behavior also in the example.

Comment: That's new.. Did you also add import(data.table) to your NAMESPACE?

Comment: Yes, I did. I could in the meanwhile fix the issues in the original coding. For some reason, one of my data.tables became a list after applying rbind and even after applying setDT it was still a list. I had to explicitely copy and cast to a data.table using as.data.table. I'm trying to reproduce this also in the example.

Comment: @utal is it still an issue for you with recent versions of testthat and data.table? is my answer applicable?

Answer (score 1):

To long for comment so posting as answer.

1. Don't use underscore in package name, it breaks the standard. Underscores will be turned to dots.
2. Can't really tell you why testthat failed to process your test. You can try to export `test` function. It is not exported so should be used only with `:::` explicitly. Maybe testthat depends on that in some way, don't know.
3. Test is passing when I move tests out of testthat. If you fail to resolve it I would look for support in testthat issues.

You can see my fork [jangorecki/test_datatable_testthat](https://github.com/jangorecki/test_datatable_testthat) of your pkg (url won't work in few days from now so fetch the changes if you want to access them later).
Your test moved out of testthat is in `tests/test.R`, content below.

```
dt <- test.datatable.testthat:::test()
expected_res <- structure(list(TYPE = c("ERROR", "ERROR"),
                               MESSAGE = c("Test","1234567890")),
                          row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table","data.frame"),
                          .Names = c("TYPE", "MESSAGE"))
stopifnot(all.equal(dt,expected_res))
```

Testthat test is suppressed by changing it to dummy, kind of `TRUE==TRUE`.
Now your test defined outside of testthat pass OK.
Related part from `00check.log`:

```
* checking tests ...
  Running ‘test.R’
  Running ‘testthat.R’
 OK
* DONE
```

Comment: ad 2. I have successfully tested non-exported functions before, so I do not expect the issue to be there.
ad 3. I had a look at testthat issues. There seems to be a discussion around whether the related issue https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/192 is resolved or not, e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252231/r-data-table-breaks-in-exported-functions

Comment: @utal consider accepting answer, otherwise please provide feedback why it doesn't address your question

Answer (score 0):

See this [issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2053) to learn of the complicated history of `testthat` and `data.table`. The good news is, it is solved.

This `data.table` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html) is very helpful

> Testing using testthat
>
> It is very common to use the testthat package for purpose of tests.
> Testing a package that imports data.table is no different from testing
> other packages. An example test script tests/testthat/test-pkg.R:
>
> context("pkg tests")
>
> test_that("generate dt", { expect_true(nrow(gen()) == 100) })
> test_that("aggregate dt", { expect_true(nrow(aggr(gen())) < 100) })
>
> If data.table is in Suggests (but not Imports) then you need to
> declare .datatable.aware=TRUE in one of the R/* files to avoid “object
> not found” errors when testing via testthat::test_package or
> testthat::test_check.