# R testthat and devtools: why does a minimal unit test break my package?

Tags: r, devtools, r-s4

I'm working on an R package for sparse matrix handling. It kinda works; here's a minimal example to set the stage for my question.

```
devtools::install_github("ekernf01/MatrixLazyEval", ref = "eef5593ad")
library(Matrix)
library(MatrixLazyEval)
data(CAex)
M = rbind(CAex, CAex)
M = matrix(stats::rnorm(prod(dim(M))), nrow = nrow(M))
M_lazy = AsLazyMatrix( M )
svd_lazy = RandomSVDLazyMatrix(M_lazy)
```

But, when I run even a minimal unit test, it breaks the package permanently (I have to restart my R session or reinstall the package). The immediate cause is that R can't find some S4 methods from packages I depend on (e.g. for matrix transpose `t` or `colSums` from the `Matrix` package). I run the unit test like this:

```
devtools::test(filter = "minimal")
svd_lazy = RandomSVDLazyMatrix(M_lazy)
```

Here's the contents of the test files.

```
> cat tests/testthat.R
library(testthat)
testthat::test_check("MatrixLazyEval")
> cat tests/testthat/testthat_minimal.R
context("minimal")
```

Why does this happen? Maybe this is naive, but the unit test shouldn't even do anything.

Edit

Possibly related:

[r - data.table and testthat package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547235/r-data-table-and-testthat-package)

https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/192

[R data.table breaks in exported functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252231/r-data-table-breaks-in-exported-functions)

Comment: Since my minimal example requires you to run `devtools::test()` within my package, it's not so easy to just give it a spin. Can anyone suggest a simpler strategy?

Comment: This may be a devtools problem. See devtools issue #192. https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import all the generics you're using in your package namespace:

```r
#' @importFrom Matrix t tcrossprod colSums rowMeans
NULL
```

This will fix the issue that you're observing and you'll be able the tests multiple times in the same session.

Also this will allow other packages that import `Matrix::t` to consistently use your custom methods. Currently, since you're calling `setMethod()` in your package, you're creating a new `t()` generic local to your namespace whenever Matrix is not attached to the search path at load-time (this is why it worked the first time you ran the tests). This prevents other packages using `Matrix::t()` to access your methods. Importing `Matrix::t()` explicitly will fix this because you'll never create a local generic for `t()`.